# Running rootless docker containers with different users

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've just recently started exploring rootless docker and there are some things that I don't fully grasp. Below is my understanding of the concept and some questions. Please correct me if something's wrong

With rootless, the daemon and containers can be run as non-root users to mitigate potential vulnerabilities, e.g. if someone were to gain access to a container running as root, then he could also have root if he got outside of the container (and into the host system). So, if someone were to gain access to a rootless container, then he'd only be able to act as the non-root user running the container.

I want to run multiple containers that don't need any network between them, so I'm thinking that it would probably make sense to not run them as the same user, but is that correct? Also, in such a scenario, would I need to install and run the daemon multiple times for each user?

What about the user inside the container. I've tried out `pihole/pihole` and the default user inside the container is root (id: 0). Is that now ok, as the container is otherwise rootless? I've tried setting it to a different user by using `user: "1005:1005"` (in docker-compose.yml), but then the container is not able to start as it's missing permissions to do some tasks).